# How To Upload Existing WordPress Site To WordPress Multisite Using SSH

Tags: multisite, uploads, mysql, import, ssh

I have a WordPress site that needs to move into a WordPress Multisite. I tried to find the site file to upload in `wp-content/uploads/sites` but I couldn't locate the file. I also tried to upload the MySQL databases but I could not change the Multisite site database prefix.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can import a site into Multisite? The fully way instead of just the pages and posts using WordPress import.

Answer (score 0):

Every WordPress site is capable of Multisite from the perspective of the files contained in each. What has to happen is to run some scripts that will prepare the database and file structure, as well as deliver the necessary changes that you will need to make in your .htaccess and wp-config.php files. Everything that you'll need is explained in this page of the codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Essentially, you'll trigger a change by adding a constant to your wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

Once you've saved that in the file, you need to go to the Tools menu in the dashboard and run the Network setup script. When that is finished, you will be given two snippets of code to place in the htaccess and wp-config respectively. Once you've done that, you'll need to login again, and you will now have a network admin separate from the dashboard for your main site.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean I have a multisite enabled and is working just that I would like to import another external WordPress site into the network with all the plugins and configuration intact.